# How to play youtube video directly to webview for sdk > 19? android

Tags: android

How to play youtube video directly in an android web view? I can play my videos in the devices with SDK < 19 by using load url.. For SDK > 19. only a white screen appear in web view.

please do help me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

*Please try this code it works for me*

```
String item = "http://www.youtube.com/embed/";

String ss = "your url";
ss = ss.substring(ss.indexOf("v=") + 2);
item += ss;
DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
int w1 = (int) (metrics.widthPixels / metrics.density), h1 = w1 * 3 / 5;
wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
wv.setWebChromeClient(chromeClient);
wv.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);

try {
    wv.loadData(
    "<html><body><iframe class=\"youtube-player\" type=\"text/html5\" width=\""
    + (w1 - 20)
    + "\" height=\""
    + h1
    + "\" src=\""
    + item
    + "\" frameborder=\"0\"\"allowfullscreen\"></iframe></body></html>",
                            "text/html5", "utf-8");
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

private WebChromeClient chromeClient = new WebChromeClient() {

    @Override
    public void onShowCustomView(View view, CustomViewCallback callback) {
        super.onShowCustomView(view, callback);
        if (view instanceof FrameLayout) {
            FrameLayout frame = (FrameLayout) view;
            if (frame.getFocusedChild() instanceof VideoView) {
                VideoView video = (VideoView) frame.getFocusedChild();
                frame.removeView(video);
                video.start();
            }
        }

    }
};
```